# Send requests to Django through uWSGI

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, uwsgi

I have two dockers, one with nginx (Docker N) and another with django rest framework(Docker D), i have the typical set up :

```
the web client <-> the web server <-> the socket <-> uwsgi <-> Django
```

Now, i need to communicate with Django Rest Framework using the API endpoints, but internally , that is, inside the docker D.

I don't want to use requests.get(http://my.website.com/api) because it will necessarily access the outside world and back, not very efficient.

Is there a way to connect directly to the websocket from uWSGI? Should i connect to the other docker (N) through nginx instead?

I tried:

```
import websocket 
from websocket import create_connection
ws = create_connection(ws://localhost:8000)
```

but i always get **websocket connection is already closed.** , fast, too fast. I can't even send anything before the exception is thrown.

Thank you.

PS:

Dockers are connected through a bridge (They connect well between them).
I can't interact with Django on localhost , unless i run it through "python manage.py runserver" . It seems i need to go through the uwsgi socket or nginx.

What i would like is to do everything inside the same Docker (The one with the Django Rest Framework)

Other people suggest using the domain with requests, not what i am looking for.

Comment: this is more a docker and networking problem than a python problem. Are you running your containers under any orchestration system? How does it handle networking? Are you exposing ports on these containers? How do connections from the outside world get in?

Comment: All containers are connected through a bridge, this isn't a connectivity issue between dockers, they have all ports exposed between them. I am not using any orchrestration system.
I can't connect using localhost:8000, unless i run Django without uWSGI, (manage.py runserver...). It seems if i deploy django through uWSGI, i will need to go through the socket uWSGI is serving.

Comment: i think you may be confused about the separation or lack their of between uwsgi and django. `./manage.py runserver` is a django runner, and uwsgi can be a django runner, but they're not really separate. The only port that will be listened on is the port uwsgi opens up.

Comment: I understand that, but i can't figure out, why i can connect to the port when i deploy django using manage.py runserver, but can't when i use uWSGI

Comment: what are your arguments/config for uwsgi to tell it what to listen on? are they the same as for runserver? like, `0.0.0.0:8000` for runserver, what's your `http-socket` for uwsgi?

Comment: This is my uwsgi.ini https://pastebin.pl/view/a336d653
This is working well with nginx, and nginx doesn't work if i use http instead of --socket :8008

Comment: @Macattack i kind of solved my problem, by running two instances of the uwsgi, one is only for internal use, do you think this is bad practice?  I will read more about uwsgi emperor.  What will happen if both uwsgi try to access the same resources/apps?

Comment: it isn't really an issue to run multiple instances of uwsgi. If you were going to scale to any level you'd run multiple uwsgi processes anyway so there would be multiple accessing the same resources anyway. Not sure what database backend you're using, but if it's an actual database like postgres or mysql they're fine with parallel access.

Comment: @Macattack its working fine, doing some stress tests and its handling it well. I'm using MariaDB . Thank you very much for your tips.